# A limit involving irrational powers: can I use L'Hopital?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x^{\sqrt 2}+1)^{\sqrt 2}}{x^2+1}$$
My first instinct was to use L'Hopital, but it just makes things messier (because of the irrational power), and after applying it four times, I gave up on it.

How else might I evaluate this limit?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x^{\sqrt 2}+1)^{\sqrt 2}}{x^2+1} &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2\left(1+x^{-\sqrt 2}\right)^{\sqrt 2}}{x^2 \left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}\\
& =\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac 1{x^{\sqrt 2}}\right)^{\sqrt 2}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}\\
&=1
\end{align}

Can you see how?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to apply L'hopital's 4 times; after two applications the denominator will be a constant function and it should be easy to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=1/t$ and compute instead
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}
\frac{\left(\dfrac{1}{\mathstrut t^{\sqrt{2}}}+1\right)^{\!\sqrt{2}}}{\dfrac{1}{t^2}+1}
=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{(1+t^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}}}{1+t^2}
$$